# How to avoid duplicate template parameters in nested template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated BST class and a node struct as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {

    T value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

template <typename Node, typename T>
class BST {

public:

    Node* m_root;

public:

    BST() {
        m_root = NULL;
    }

    bool find(T value, Node** parent, Node** location) {/* ... */}
}
```

I need to know the template argument of the struct inside the BST class and I instantiate the BST as follows:

```
BST<Node<int>, int>* bst = new BST<Node<int>, int>();
```

Which is a bit ugly.

I would like

```
BST<Node<int>>* bst = new BST<Node<int>>();
```

and deduce the T template parameter in BST from the struct template parameter.

I tried `template < template<typename T> class Node>` which don't seem to work (`T` is unknown in the `find()` declaration).

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to be `Node` a nested class of `BST`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass `Node` as template parameter at all there?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ can't wrap my head around templates yet a.k.a. very little experience with it. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: `template <template<typename> class Node, typename T>` would work if your code said `BST<Node,int>* bst = new BST<Node,int>();`

Comment: Here is an example: https://onlinegdb.com/HJinYonDm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

- The simpler, and I think what you want:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class BST {
  public:
      Node<T>* m_root = nullptr;

  public:
      BST() = default;

      // ...
  };
  ```

  with usage

  ```
  BST<int> bst;
  ```
- Other one is specialization:

  ```
  template <typename T> class BST;

  template <typename T>
  class BST<Node<T>> {
  public:
      Node<T>* m_root = nullptr;

  public:
      BST() = default;

      // ...
  };
  ```

  with usage:

  ```
  BST<Node<int>> bst;
  ```
- and a last one, template template parameter:

  ```
  template <template <typename> class N, typename T>
  class BST {
  public:
      N<T>* m_root = nullptr;

  public:
      BST() = default;

      // ...
  };
  ```

  with usage

  ```
  BST<Node, int> bst;
  ```

Comment: Is it correct that in the second example you have written the forward declaration for the template BST  `template <typename T> class BST;`?  I thought it must have been the forward declaration for Node.

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov: In all cases, I assume `Node` is defined before (in first case, it could even be inner class, but that is an other story). In second case I declare the primary template (without definition, but it could have one) to be able to (partially) specialize it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the primary template to take only one template parameter, and add a partial speclizaition.

```
template <typename T>
class BST;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
class BST<C<T>> {
    using Node = C<T>;
public:
    BST() {
        m_root = NULL;
    }

    bool find(T value, Node** parent, Node** location) {/* ... */}
};
```

Then you can use it like

```
BST<Node<int>>* bst = new BST<Node<int>>(); // deduce C as Node, T as int
```

Or add some nested typedefs.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    using value_type = T;
    ...
};

template <typename Node>
class BST {
    using T = typename Node::value_type;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
template <typename T>
class BST {

public:

    Node< T >* m_root;

public:

    BST() {
        m_root = NULL;
    }

    bool find(T value, Node< T >** parent, Node< T >** location) {/* ... */}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should nest `Node` inside of `BST`:

```
template <typename T>
class BST
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    BST() { m_root = NULL; }

    bool find(T value, Node** parent, Node** location) {/* ... */}

private:
    Node* m_root;
};
```

Comment: I think this answer provides a "fix of design" - a nice alternative to the other answers which provide "fixes of code".